# How to initialise Short array in Kotlin?

Tags: arrays, kotlin, short

There are multiple ways to declare and initialise Arrays in Kotlin. An `Array<Short>` can be initialised in the following ways -

```
val shortArr1 = shortArrayOf(1,2,3,4,5)
//or
val shortArr2: Array<Short> = arrayOf(1,2,3,4,5)
```

But, what if the values are complicated and I want to initialise the values using a lambda function, such as -

```
val shortArr3 = Array<Short>(10){n -> n*2}
```

This statement throws -

```
error: type mismatch: inferred type is Int but Short was expected
```

The above expression would have worked for an `Array<Int>` since `n` by default is of type Int. Hence, what is the correct way to initialise an Array using lambda function, in Kotlin?

Comment: Note that `Array<Short>` and `ShortArray` are two different things. Most of the time, you'll want `ShortArray`. An `Array<Short>` is an array of references to short values, where the short values themselves may not be contiguous even if their references are. An Array<Short> also wastes space. Each short is 16 bits, but each element of an `Array<Short>` uses typically 64 bits for the reference plus 16 bits for the value, plus some further overhead, plus the CPU overhead of garbage collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To initialize an Array using a lambda function in Kotlin, you can explicitly specify the type of the lambda parameter as Short. Here's the correct way to initialize the array:

val shortArr3 = Array(10) { n: Int -> (n * 2).toShort() }

In this example, the lambda function takes an Int parameter n and multiplies it by 2. The result is then converted to Short using the toShort() function.

By explicitly specifying the type of the lambda parameter as n: Int, you ensure that the multiplication operation is performed with Int values and then converted to Short explicitly. This resolves the type mismatch error.